# How fast is the water draining out after 5 min?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The volume $V$, in liters, of water in a water tank after $t$ min it
>   starts draining, is given by $$V(t)=260(60−t)^2$$ How fast is the
>   water draining out after 5 min?

Do I calculate the volume at $t=0$ and $t=5$ and then take the answer minus each other and then divide the answer to $5$ or do I derive the function and then fill in $5$?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Should the answer depend on what happened in the first five minutes or should it be only depended on what happens at exactly 5 minutes into observing? What would you say?

Answer (score 3):

HINT : Take derivative with respect to t and substitute  $5$

(because rate or how fast(Instantaneous change) is what is asked in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question asks "how fast is the water draining" at a particular time.  Since the question asks for the rate of change at a particular instant, you need to find the derivative rather than the average rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

$V(t)=260(60−t)^2$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = -520(60-t)$

$V'(5) = -520(60-5) =$ ???